# GStreamer illegal hardware instruction

Tags: macos, clang, homebrew, gstreamer

I am trying to learn GStreamer. I am using macOS 10.13-x86_64.
I started working on [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/hello-world.html) tutorial.

Initially I installed GStreamer *.pkg* files.
GStreamer was installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework`
I managed to compile and run the tutorial but I was required to use `sudo` to access `/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework` directory.

Later I found out that I can install GStreamer via homebrew.
So, I manually removed `/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework` and run the following command:

```
brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-libav
```

Unfortunately, this tutorial now throws run-time error.

```
./basic-1
[1]    1873 illegal hardware instruction  ./basic-1
```

I tried to debug the error with lldb (I very new to lldb and almost can nothing).

```
lldb basic-1
(lldb) target create "basic-1"
Current executable set to 'basic-1' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 2129 launched: '/Users/aleksey/projects/media/gstreamer-dummy/basic-1' (x86_64)
Process 2129 stopped
* thread #14, stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff3b0e3939 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDeallocate + 537
CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDeallocate:
->  0x7fff3b0e3939 <+537>: ud2
    0x7fff3b0e393b <+539>: nopl   (%rax,%rax)

CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopCleanseSources:
    0x7fff3b0e3940 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff3b0e3941 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
Target 0: (basic-1) stopped.
```

And I know don't what to do with this.

I compile the code with

```
gcc -Wall basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-1 $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0)
```

and I have the following config

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.41/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.12.3/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.54.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

Could you please help me with that? What is the problem?

Comment: Did you have the issue fixed, I am having the same issue now

Comment: @AlbaHoo to be honest I don't remember if I managed to fix it. I guess I didn't fix it but it became irrelevant to me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found some answers [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790242) (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790242). I am waiting for some additional comments here https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs/issues/58

In summary:

> [Remi Achard Apr 11, 2020; 7:55pmRe: Illegal hardware instructions when running basic-tutorial-1 on mac OS 10.15.2 / brew installation](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Illegal-hardware-instructions-when-running-basic-tutorial-1-on-mac-OS-10-15-2-brew-installation-td4693209.html)
>
> It appears tutorials (at least the first ones) don't work on macOS for some years now.

> [Sebastian Dröge (slomo) 2017-11-12 12:41:44 UTC]
>
> See https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs/issues/58 , same applies to the C tutorials.
>
> The problem is that for osxvideosink and glimagesink we need to run a
> NSRunLoop on the main thread on macOS. Our patched GLib version does
> that when you run a GMainLoop (upstream GLib doens't!), but the
> examples are only using gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered() so that also
> wouldn't help.
>
> Using a GMainLoop would make the tutorials quite a bit more
> complicated, more API would have to be introduced, there would always
> be callbacks, etc.
>
> Not sure what to do about this!

Possible solution:

> [Kornel 2017-11-12 13:34:16 UTC]
>
> I've managed to get simple examples working by running the example on
> a thread, and calling CFRunLoopRun() on the main thread. It requires
> only linking with the foundation.framework.

---

[Update 01]
I was able to compile and run successfully the [Basic tutorial 12: Streaming](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/streaming.html?gi-language=c).

---

[Update 02]

> From: Sebastian Dröge [Dec 29, 2020 11:53am GMT+0100]
>
> It's not that you need a GLib main loop, but macOS requires you to
> run a NSRunLoop on the main thread for various macOS APIs to work
> correctly. The GStreamer video sinks use such APIs. The GLib mainloop
> (from the GLib version shipped with the GStreamer binaries!) runs a
> NSRunLoop itself for this very reason. This is a limitation on macOS
> that you'll have to accommodate somehow and is unrelated to GStreamer,
> and that should probably be mentioned more prominently in the
> GStreamer documentation.
>
> More info: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/issues/79

---

Other related posts [1](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Illegal-hardware-instructions-when-running-basic-tutorial-1-on-mac-OS-10-15-2-brew-installation-td4693209.html), [3](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-docs/-/issues/10), [4](https://github.com/sdroege/gstreamer-rs/issues/58).